# Laravel 8 rich text editor problems

Tags: laravel, tinymce

I'm using tinymce editor 6.8 and laravel 8 but when I put a picture using this editor it hasn't shown in the other pages like the edit page to edit my post or to the blog post page to see the full page with title,body and pictures.

Also, the body that I wrote showed

tag in blog post page instead of the text I wrote so I replaced this:

{{ Str::limit($post->body,'20','....') }}

with this:

{!! Str::limit($post->body,'20','....') !!}

it shows nothing from the body that I wrote, also the route that below the tag didn't work it showed in the inspector without the slash:

Read More →

and in the database it also showed the tag , and when I try to edit my post it showed the text without the picture I created with the post Can you help me with this? p.s: All things were worked perfectly before I used the tiny mce editor